# ACH file creation using Powershell giving error in format

Tags: format

I have created an ach file which, in a text editor looks exactly like a valid ach file. When I open it in an ACH viewer tool I get an error saying that the first character must be 1. I found this in the NACHA file specs 'Picture: This is the type of bit the ACH system is expecting to see. A 9 indicates a numeric value and an X indicates an
alphabetic value. **If you put a letter in a PIC 9 position**, the system will reject the field. If you see a number in parentheses
after the X or 9, that indicates the number of characters in that field. For example 9(10) means that field contains 10
numeric characters.'

The first position in the file is supposed to have content 1 in Picture format of size 1. I don't understand what do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally downloaded a Hex file explorer and saw that the valid ACH file and my file both had different first characters. I found out that the ACH file needs the data in the ASCII format. All I had to do was when I populated the ACH file with data, I converted the data to ASCII before writing it.